# Custom URL routes helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

It seems there is no URL helper generated automatically when you apply custom.

So below is what is defined in my `routes.rb` file but when I do `rake routes` I don't have any URL helper generated at all.

```
get "events/display_event/:id", :to => "events#display_event"
```

It seems it is generated only for resources in the routes.

Is there a way to generate this automatically or do I have to manually specify without using the helper?

If it has to be done manually in the view, what is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
get "events/display_event/:id" => "events#display_event", as: :display_event
```

Comment: darn, you're quick!  :)  Very much the right answer, I agree with @yosep-kim  -- you're looking for `as`

Comment: Thanks man. I'm Korean aswell by the way. I think we need more Korean Ruby programmers!!!

Comment: Awesome. I am glad to see a fellow Korean developer. Please, hit the upvote and vote it as an answer. 고마워요!